# how to add class on button click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I make a simple directive .I have two button on that directive .I am able to get click event of that button .But I want to add class on that .

I have one class

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I want to add this class whenever button is click ..

- Intially **login** button have red class .When logout button is click it apply on **logout** button and remove from **login** button

or again if I click on login button it apply on login button and remove from logout button ..

I do like that

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).directive('tm', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    scope: {
      login: "&",
      logout: '&'
    },
    controller: 'f',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };
})
```

here is code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1e8u0okOa4looLcb2YO?p=preview

Comment: use `ngClass`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: I am trying to do with ngClass ..I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a link function

Try like this

```
link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
  elm.find("button").on("click", function(e) {
    elm.find("button").removeClass("red");
    angular.element(this).addClass("red");
  })
}
```

<kbd>**[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/PeqD63A3Kr7K6y6VjcKa?p=preview)**</kbd>

Or you can do it using **[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

Like this

**JS**

```
vm.isLogin = true;
vm.login = function() {
  vm.isLogin = true;
}

vm.logout = function() {
  vm.isLogin = false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-class="{'red': vm.isLogin }"  ng-click='vm.login()'>Login</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'red': !vm.isLogin }" ng-click='vm.logout()'>logount</button>
```

<kbd>**[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/moRWlBzXRblcloF4MBJD?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: got it  your answer is correct..but I am looking for  using ng-class .Mean I want to write my logic o controller .I want to take one variable ..and that variable become true and false

Comment: your logic is fail when there 3 button ..and I want to do this only for first two button..it apply on all button

Comment: nope it'll work for all button though i have added your ngClass part @user944513

Comment: thanks i have one Question ..you are correct ...how vm is define in controller.we are not passsing to directive how vm.isLogin works.. see my plunker..http://plnkr.co/edit/Xw9ensF5zdnZv0rlE6I7?p=preview

Comment: I changed controllerAs: 'vmm', and  ng-click='vmm.login()'  ..but vm.login still work..why ? how directive knows it is true or false ..it is written in controller

Comment: I think the best way to pass isLogin  to dirctive scope ..may i correct

Comment: It's working becuase you didn't remove link function from your plnkr @user944513

Comment: It's actually depend on your business. Like this color changing is not the issue which will be considered by the developer. It should be a default feature of  this directive according to the business.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98625/discussion-between-user944513-and-anik-islam-abhi).

Comment: hello
@anil
plnkr.co/edit/…
see this
lik
vm.isLogin=true; 
vm.p='kk'
I added one line this vm.p
try to access this <div> 
hello{{vm.p}} 
</div>
it is not accessable
but why vm.islogin accessable
?

Comment: My name is anik :) Well your controller as is `vmm` not `vm` .. it's can't access any of this . check your console for more info @user944513